# How can I simply order my x values on a sns.boxplot according to chronological dates in my dataframe

Tags: python, sorting, plot

[this is the code, I should order the dates chronologically (data is starting from october)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkEUO.png)

[This is my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtz0f.png)

Comment: Could you please add your code and output as a text instead of images?

Comment: I am trying to get it fixed

Comment: @gmauch Thanks for your swift reaction, but i found it!